# jQuery/JavaScript not working inside script tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want, my HTML document to output random numbers for Dungeons and Dragons. However, the code isn't working and I can't workout why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#d4").click(function(){
    var out = Math.random(1,4);
    alert(out);
  };
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id ="d4">Roll a d4</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How isn't it working?

Comment: put your document.ready code in separate script tag after jquery script tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The script tag cannot have the src attribute and a body, you need to use separate script tags

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#d4").click(function () {
        var out = Math.random(1, 4);
        alert(out);
    }); //missing ) here
});
</script>
```

[Script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) src

> This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be
>   used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a
>   document. script elements with an src attribute specified should not
>   have a script embedded within its tags.

Answer (score 2):

After alert you need to close the parenthesis to the click function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#d4").click(function(){
        var out = Math.random(1,4);
        alert(out);
    }); // <-- here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing click function's closing parenthesis.